# Load dashboard components individually with loading icon on them asp.net core

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on .net core dashboard with lots of graphs and data and when we load dashboard it look time, i want to load my dashboard first then widgets with loading icon on them, as every widgets get own data it will show

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided? In addition, you could have a look here for [`details implementaion`](https://code-maze.com/creating-blazor-webassembly-signalr-charts/)

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple component for demonstration purposes

Component.razor:

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_message))
{
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
}
else
{
    <h3>@_message</h3>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Delay { get; set; }

    private string _message;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // SIMULATING data fetching or other initialization task
        await Task.Delay(Delay);

        _message = "Done";
    }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<Component Delay="5000"></Component>

<Component Delay="15000"></Component>

<Component Delay="10000"></Component>
```

[image: demo]

As you can see, each component updates as soon as it's ready. The same can be applied to more complex scenarios like your dashboard.

Comment: we can not add time manually, its based on data user is fetching we need a automated way

Comment: It's just a demonstration... Instead of `Component.razor` use your own components and instead of `await Task.Delay(Delay);` call the tasks to initialize your components e.g. an api call to fetch data.